# How Do I Perfectly Center a Float Element in Between Two Floated Elements?

Tags: html, css

I am finding it difficult to center a text in between two other texts.

**HMTL**:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="footer">
        <span class="left_edge">@left</span>
        <span class="center">@center</span>
        <span class="right_edge">@right</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.footer{
    background: #e33;
    padding: 5px;
}
.left_edge{
    float: left;
}
.center{
    float: left;
}
.left_edge{
    float: right;
}
```

How do I perfectly center the `.center` as shown in the correctly marked image?

[image]

Comment: Don't use spans.  Use divs.  The use text-align:center on the center one.  Also, set the width to 100%.  That will fill the allotted area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach would be to set the `display` of the middle element to `inline-block` and then use `text-align: center` on the parent element for horizontal centering:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vy9xv225/)

```
.footer {
    background: #e33;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.left_edge {
    float: left;
}
.center {
    display: inline-block;
}
.right_edge {
    float: right;
}
```

Alternatively, you could avoid floating the elements, and use the following method instead:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gktyc01j/)

```
.footer > span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.333%
}
.left_edge {
    text-align: left;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.right_edge {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: It did it, like charm! Muchas gratias!

Comment: If possible use his second example. Floats have a tendency to perform poorly and behave unexpectedly in dynamic pages. I advise my front-end guys to use float only when it is necessary to wrap inline elements or text around an image or similar element.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works when the floating elements are always present and they always have the same width, but when one or both of them are missing or their width changes, the position of the central element starts to move left and right.

Imagine that you have a multi-line list of values that needs to be displayed as a table - if everything is done in separate columns, then the available space is not used optimally, but if you do the alignment within one cell with floating elements, then the central element also “floats” relative to the center - since the position of center is calculated based on the entire width, including floating elements.

**HTML**:

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td class="container"><span class="left">left</span><span class="center">center</span><span class="right"></span></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td class="container"><span class="left"></span><span class="center">center</span><span class="right"></span></td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td class="container"><span class="left">left</span><span class="center">center</span><span class="right">right</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td class="container"><span class="left"></span><span class="center">center</span><span class="right">right</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container { width: 400px }
span.left { float: left }
span.center { }
span.right { float: right }
```

The following would help fix this:

```
span.center { position: absolute; left: 200px; width: 50% }
```

But it's not always possible to use absolute positioning, for example when the table is in a scrollable container. And if pseudo classes after and before are used for floating elements, then this is also not always possible.

So what should we do then?